# webhdfs open file NullPointerException

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs, cloudera-cdh

I am trying open a file from HDFS throught the webhdfs API. I can create files and upload them, but once I try to open I get this error

```
{"RemoteException":{"exception":"NullPointerException","javaClassName":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":null}}
```

using the following command

```
curl -i -X GET "http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/tmp.txt?op=OPEN"
```

I tried this from multiple machines (from the master node, or remotely) I get the same error. It's running on CHD4.6.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently this is a bug in CDH running on Ubuntu 12.04, due to /run mounted with noexec

can be resolved as follows:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /run
```